# Jquery dialog to open another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-dialog

There is a page as transaction.html

How to open this page in a popup in another page say show_transactions.html in a jquery dialog

```
       $dialog.html()  //open transaction.html in this dialog
     .dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        position: 'center' ,
        title: 'EDIT',
        draggable: false,
        width : 300,
        height : 40, 
        resizable : false,
        modal : true,
     });
     alert('here');
     $dialog.dialog('open');
```

This code is present in show_transactions.html

Thanks..

Comment: So you're opening a pop-up, and then opening a jQuery UI Dialog in that pop-up? Or are you loading show_transactions into a jQuery Dialog?

Comment: No ,show transactiona is a normal page on which i am trying to open a popup

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.load()` method to load a page into a dialog, here's how:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center' ,
    title: 'EDIT',
    draggable: false,
    width : 300,
    height : 40, 
    resizable : false,
    modal : true,
});

$("#dialog_trigger").click( function() {
    $("#dialog").load('path/to/file.html', function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
})
```

This assumes the dialog has an ID of 'dialog' and that there's another element with ID of 'dialog_trigger' that is clicked to open it. You'd put both of these into your document's ready function so that the dialog is made on page-load, if it isn't, it will cause a slight-but-noticeable delay for the user as it's made.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do like this...

**Create dialog page**

```
<div id="MyDialogID"  title="My Dialog Title"></div>
```

**Create a link** (when we click on that link it will open the dialog)

```
<a id="MyLinkToDialogID" href="Path to Dialog Page">Open My Dialog</a>
```

**Initialise the dialog** (create an event between the link and the dialog)

```
$('#MyLinkToDialogID').each(function () {
    var $link = $(this);

    $.post($link.attr('href'), function (data) {
        var $dialog = $(data)
            .filter('#MyDialogID')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 240,
                width: 370,
                modal: true
            });

            $link.click(function () {
               $dialog.dialog("open");
               $dialog.css("height", "240");
               $dialog.css("width", "370px");
               $dialog.dialog({ position: 'center' });

               return false;
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Although that link may provide an answer to the question, you should include what you can _here_ on Stack Overflow. If that page is deleted in future, this answer becomes obsolete.