# How to make a webpage look like a popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page on which an anchor tag `<a href="other-page.php">` links to another page.

I want this `other-page.php` appear like a pop-up on the page which contains the aforementioned `<a>` tag.

Is it possible using CSS and/or JQuery?

If yes, what is the general idea? How to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are a lot of ways to do it. I'm assuming you just want to call the HTML from the other page and have it load in a DIV that is shown like a popup? Please provide some amount of code of what you have tried.

Comment: Have a look at this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1328731/4322803

Comment: @Quantumplate JQuery UI would be a bit bloated for just one link. It will do the job of making a dialog box.

Comment: it is called a Modal Popup... check this example: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: @Twisty Haven't written an code yet, I didn't even know if it is possible. I searched on the web with terms like "popup using css" etc. but none of the results was loading a new page in a popup. So I was half thinking that it is not possible. Now I'll search for modal windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery dialog to open another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756283/jquery-dialog-to-open-another-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the link to open up a new browser window, you need the 'target' attribute on the anchor tag, like this:
`<a href="other-page.php" target="_blank">`

If you don't want a full browser window, just a pop-out window with an 'x' close tab, you're looking for a "modal" window. There are modal jquery libraries that will do that. Check out [simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/). That's just one of many libraries, but now you have a search term.

Answer (score 1):

**You have 2 choices:**

***- The firstone*** is act like that, just 1 page, put all the content in just 1 html. Put display: none; to all the other divs(all what you don't want show to the user) and then via JS change the visibility via

```
$('div').show;
/* or*/
 $('div').hide;
```

***- The secondone:*** is display:none or visibility:hidden to a global div (within all the page content) in visibility: hidden, or display:none and change it via:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(divToShow).show('slow');
/* or */
 $(divToShow).slideup('slow');
/* or some effect */
});
```

The lastone it make a modal but depend the content It's 
non-viable

Hope I helped,